# Can I use imagick with php in tidesdk?

Tags: php, tidesdk

Can I add extensions like php imagick ? I use php for image processing with imagick. So any way to install it ?

And is there any way that user can select images from there computer or my app can scan computer for images like that ? because php can't do that. Just wanted to know if your sdk provides to communicate with the file system.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick relies on the proper version of ImageMagick binaries to be installed and in the path of the host system, which would be a separate installation.

PHP *can* scan your computer for photos *if* you're running it locally. With a PHP app hosted on a web server, you're not. With TideSDK, you are. It should be possible to scan a directory for all files with photo extensions like .jpg and .png.